# Changing the height of the child components to the height of Parent Components using ref React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Currently, I'm stuck on how to change the Height of child elements to the height of their parent elements. I've read the documentation about the "ref" in react but I don't think it is usable in my senario as I've multiple Divs having two Childs in it. I've done that in jQuery but not in react. Any Suggestions. Here is my code.

```
        class EventDisplay extends React.Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
        }


        render() {


            return (
                <div>
                    <div className="ecs-event-list row ">
                    <div className="event1Parent">
                        <div className="event1Child"> zxcasd </div>
                        <div className="event1Child">zsxcasd</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="event2Parent">
                        <div className="event2Child">zxcasd</div>
                        <div className="event2Child">asxcasd</div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="event3Parent">
                        <div className="event3Child">zxcasd</div>
                        <div className="event3Child">asxcasd</div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );

        }
        }


        ReactDOM.render(<EventDisplay />, document.querySelector("#app"))

    <div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the question. Setting css property height to 100% on child elements will result in them having the height of the parent. Does it solve the problem ?

Comment: No I don't want to  do that. I want to use react to make the height of childs according to their parent height. As this is just dummy scenario. let's say there are different events having information stored in it some divs height is large because of content and some divs are of small. so in that case what you do

Comment: So yeah setup ref on parent divs to get their height and set the height of children's to that value

Comment: Any demonstration, As I'm not pro Also can you define ref in an easy way ?